# Regex that matches even amount of character

Tags: regex

**Disclamer** (after solved): this is my uni assignment thus I the answer could be simple. Hints are shown but my answer is hidden from here. Alternative answers could be found here but I take no responsibility with any plagiarism with direct answers posted here.

---

Hi I'm having troubles with the following exercise

Find regex that strictly represents the language:

```
b^(m+1), such that m>=0, m mod 2 = 1
```

The language breaks down to words:

```
{bb,bbbb,bbbbbb,bbbbbbbb,...}
```

I have tried the following:

```
b(bbb)?(bb)*
```

But this also accepts

```
{bb,bbb,bbbb,bbbbb,...}
```

Is there a way to write it such one bit of expression is depended on the other? ie: (bb)* cannot be chosen if (bbb)? is chosen at once, then repeat the decision but allow the vice versa.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Update:-***
You can use

```
^(?:bb)+$
```

[`Regex Demo`](https://regex101.com/r/Mf37Kb/2/)

> Initial heading of question was --> Regex that matches odd amount of character

You can try this

```
^b(?:(?:b{2})+)?$
```

[image]

[`Regex Demo`](https://regex101.com/r/Mf37Kb/1/)

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that, this might be closer,

```
^(?:bb){1,}$
```

and your set might look like,

```
bb
bbbb
bbbbbb
```

not sure though. If your set was correct, expression can likely be modified.

---

also, `b` would not probably be in the set, since m=0 does not pass the second requirement.

---

> If you wish to explore/simplify/modify the expression, it's been
>   explained on the top right panel of
>   [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/Tp1UVA/1/). If you'd like, you
>   can also watch in [this
>   link](https://regex101.com/r/Tp1UVA/1/debugger), how it would match
>   against some sample inputs.

---

Comment: Unfortunately, the question requires me to provide an expression such that it ONLY accepts the set. That means it should not accept bb bbb bbbbb because my sets are {b,bbbb,bbbbbb...}

Comment: Oh yes! b would not be in the set. thank you!.. Will edit and see this again

Comment: I have just tried your expression. it is almost correct, the only flaw is that your expression still accepts just b initially as well? How should we get around that?

Comment: or [this expression](https://regex101.com/r/3Dn5bi/2) hahaha, why did we complicate things... Thanks anyway!

Comment: @ChanbothSom but your heading suggest something else `Regex that matches odd amount of character`

Comment: @Code Maniac, Thanks for pointing it out. That was before me and Emma realised my set at the time of original post was wrong.